# How to retrieve the data from a JSP textbox and display the data in a JQuery alert box in the same page?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins

I am creating a simple web page in JSP where I will one textbox and one button. Requirement is as soon as user click on the button after entering some text, the screen must display an alert displaying the entered name. I have to achieve this using one of the JQuery Plugins. Below is the sample code for your reference:

file name : b.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection,java.sql.PreparedStatement,java.sql.DriverManager,java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-confirm-master/dist/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-confirm-master/dist/jquery-confirm.min.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>JSP Test - b.jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="b.jsp">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Text:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" value=""></td>
                    <td><input type="Submit" value="Click to Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br>
        <%
            String myText = request.getParameter("myText");
            if (myText == null) {
                // myText is null when the page is first requested, 
                // so do nothing
            } else {
                if (myText.length() == 0) {
                    // There was a querystring like ?myText=
                    // but no text, so myText is not null, but 
                    // a zero length string instead.
        %>
        <b>myText is empty</b>
        <% } else {%>
        <b>myText is <%= myText%></b>
        <%
                }
            }
        %>
        <input type="button" id="alert" value="alert me" onclick="bn()">
        <script>
            function bn() {
                $.alert({
                    title: 'Alert!',
                    content: 'Simple alert!',
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, I have created separate button 'Alert' to display the alert box (using jquery plugin), but what if I want to display the alert box with the text entered in textbox id=myText inside the JQuery alert box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the script in your condition.

```
<% } else {%>
    <script>
        $.alert({
            title: 'Alert!',
            content: '<%= myText%>',
        });
    </script>
<% }%>
```

Comment: Thanks.. exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I am facing an issue. Look at my updated code, in the last I am showing the JQuery alert box with table view showing id, name and salary which I am retrieving from db. Here id and salary are getting fetched and is getting displayed in the table. But value name i.e myText is not getting displayed. Every time I used to insert myText in alert content, browser doesn't display any alert box. Getting an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined'.

Comment: Try without string concatenation. Ex: `'<tr><td><%=b%></td>'`. If the problem still exists. Please add it as a separate question.

Comment: I rolledback your edit as it does not match with the original question, and the accepted answer. Please add your next problem as a new question. It helps future readers to understand a single problem at a time.